# TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer -> using Concatenate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Error -
*
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Received: layer=KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 80, 300), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='concatenate_15/concat:0', description="created by layer 'concatenate_15'") of type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'
*

Code:

```
embedding_size = 300

model = Sequential()
model.add(
    Embedding(
        input_dim=embedding_size,
        output_dim=100,
        weights=None,
        trainable=True))

model.summary()



#Input dimension is 4096 since we will feed it the encoded version of the image.

image_model = Sequential([
        Dense(embedding_size, input_shape=(2048,), activation='relu'),
        RepeatVector(max_len)
    ])

#Since we are going to predict the next word using the previous words(length of previous words changes with every iteration over the caption), we have to set return_sequences = True.

caption_model = Sequential([
        Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=max_len),
        LSTM(256, return_sequences=True),
        TimeDistributed(Dense(300))
    ])

#Embedding

image_model.summary()


caption_model.summary()

tmodel = tf.keras.Sequential()
tmodel.add(Concatenate(axis=1)([image_model.output, caption_model.output]))
tmodel.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False)))
tmodel.add(Dense(vocab_size))
tmodel.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Error is at line Concatenate.

I am not sure what mistake I am doing. I tried with different axis.
Also tried
Concatenate([image_model, caption_model])
which gives different Error.

Comment: Concatenate is Functional API, you cannot use it in the Sequential API.